# Exit stream manually before `on('exit')` event is reached while using filewalker

Tags: javascript, node.js, filewalker

I am using `filewalker` npm package to walk through files.

I am trying to limit amount of files that would be read in stream by exiting stream once a specific condition is met. (e.g. streamed 5 file paths) rather than waiting `exit` event. (This is due to huge amount of files and I want to paginate stream)

```
  getFilePath: (dirPath, fileMatchExpression) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      filewalker(dirPath)
      .on('file', filePath => {
        if (filePath.match(fileMatchExpression)){
          resolve(filePath)
          // how to force exit on this line?
        }
      })
      .on('error', err => reject(err))
      .on('done', _ => console.log('DONE!!'))
      .walk()
    })
```

Is there a way to cancel/exit stream by manually?

Comment: try throwing an error, call reject

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix I tried rejecting, however it cancels the rest of the script, but I need to resolve value and continue executing next methods that do something with that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not answer to the question, I solved this issue by replacing `filewalker` library with `walk`. It basically does the same thing, except it has `next` function which allows me to control if program will execute next or not.

```
const walk = require('walk')
let walker = walk.walk(dataDirPath, {followingLinks: false})
let counter = 0
walker.on('file', (root, stat, next) => {
  console.log(root + '/' + stat.name);
  counter++
  if(counter < 1) next()
})
```